# Django function based view Login

Tags: django, authentication, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've been trying to write a view for users to login..

```
def LoginView(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if request.user.id:
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
                password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("/")
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                "api/login.html",
                {"massege": "the user NOT found , register here ", "form": form},
            )

    return render(request, "api/login.html", {"form": form})
```

login Form

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=65, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
```

when I try to login as user who exsits in database the funciton eccepts it as non exists user ,and display what under else condition to the template

Comment: How did you *reguster* the user?

Comment: You expect a user id before authenticate the user `if request.user.id`. That will always be false except for already logged in users.

Comment: @OulaR: please [edit] the question with the view and form that you use to *register* the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user id is always None in case of no user is login.

You can modify the code like this:

```
def LoginView(request):
    
    # redirect already login user to "/"
    if request.user.id:
        return redirect("/")
    
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                "api/login.html",
                {"massege": "the user NOT found , register here ", "form": form},
            )

    return render(request, "api/login.html", {"form": form})
```